# How to SHOW bottombar (tab bar controller)?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, hide, show

I used this to hide the bottom bar

```
-(BOOL) hidesBottomBarWhenPushed{
    return YES;
}
```

Now i'm at a point where I want to NOT to hide it anymore. What method should I use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take at look at Elements sample project. They do something like you want, especially in the ElementViewController.m file.

Comment: Thanks you, monsieur. It works. The trick is to NOT set the hidesbottombar... = YES in the parent view before push. It works as to hide to bar, but there is no way to get it shown. In stead, in the init func of the child view controller, set self.sethidesbottombar... = YES;

again, merci, monsieur.

Answer (score 0):

Thats very simple, just use this:

```
[tabBar setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:FALSE];
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time putting the puzzle of John together. So here is my final result. In the .m file of my view controller I add this code:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
    // Custom initialization
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
}
return self;}
```

Because I use a nib file I had to override the initWithNibName method.

Answer (score 0):

A really simple way:

```
 Class *instanceName = [[Class alloc] init];
 instanceName.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
 ...
 [navigationController pushViewController:instanceName animated:YES];
```